# PHP remove duplicates 3d array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a three dimensional array looking like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7839253
        [companyInfo] => Array
            (
                [companyName] => UniqueName
                [orgNumber] => 32839434
                [companyText] => UniqueText
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1729013
        [companyInfo] => Array
            (
                [companyName] => UniqueName
                [orgNumber] => 32839434
                [companyText] => UniqueText
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8731121
        [companyInfo] => Array
            (
                [companyName] => UniqueName
                [orgNumber] => 32839434
                [companyText] => UniqueText
            )
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 873112921
        [companyInfo] => Array
            (
                [companyName] => UniqueName
                [orgNumber] => 42119424
                [companyText] => UniqueText
            )
    )
)
```

I have a hard time removing these arrays matching on orgNumber. I have tried this:

```
$jsonresult = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $jsonresult)));
```

Any multiarray containing the orgnumber, the full array for that company should be remove. Not the last one though because it has a different orgNumber. Creating this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7839253
        [companyInfo] => Array
            (
                [companyName] => UniqueName
                [orgNumber] => 32839434
                [companyText] => UniqueText
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 873112921
        [companyInfo] => Array
            (
                [companyName] => UniqueName
                [orgNumber] => 42119424
                [companyText] => UniqueText
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Also what is the pattern behind this ??

Comment: Yes I have $jsonresult = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $jsonresult)));

Does not work :(

Comment: 1. ^ Include your attempts/effort into your question! 2. I don't see the pattern behind this which company arrays you want to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) looks lke an obvious approach, something like:

```
$currentOrgs = [];
$newArray = array_filter(
    $oldArray,
    function($value) use (&$currentOrgs){
        if (isset($currentOrgs[$value['companyInfo']['orgNumber']])) {
            return false;
        }
        $currentOrgs[$value['companyInfo']['orgNumber']] = true;
        return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing! Your are the king! Thank you soo much. The only thing I found it doesnt preserve the keys 5 next is 8.

Comment: Hmmm.... array_filter() should preserve keys... it should give you keys 0 and 3 from your original array

Comment: I used array_values() for it so ey'like success! Thank you so much you really did help me so much with this, i'm very grateful.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked really well. Could you help me with one more thing? What if I would like to check so the $oldarray['homepage'] is not in the same array as the similar orgnumber. In that case it should not be removed. Thanks!

Comment: Pass $oldarray['homepage'] into the closure as well, and put the additional check in the closure logic